# Login Attempts - Codeigniter - Not Working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to workout a function such that unsuccessful login attempts of user are capped at 3 consecutive failed login attempts, then serve them a message to that effect. It is immediately executing this line:

```
if ($isBlocked) {
    $this->form_validation->set_message('check_user', 'Account is temporarily blocked.');
}
```

Somethings wrong on my code. Thanks in advance for the help.

**Controller**

```
<?php
class Account_login extends CI_Controller
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  public function index()
  {
    $data['title'] = 'Account Login';
    $this->load->view('account_login', $data);
  }

  public function verify()
  {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('acc_username', 'Username', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('acc_password', 'Password', 'required|callback_check_user');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE) {
      echo 'Success';
    } else {
      $this->index();
    }
  }

  public function check_user()
  {
    $username = $this->input->post('acc_username');
    $password = $this->input->post('acc_password');


    $this->load->model('account_login_model');
    $login = $this->account_login_model->login($username, $password);


    if ($login) {
      return true;
    } else {
      if (isset($_SESSION['error_count'][$username])) {
        $_SESSION['error_count'][$username] += 1;
      } else {
        $_SESSION['error_count'][$username] = 1;
      }

      $isBlocked = $this->account_login_model->isBlocked($username);
      if ($isBlocked) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_user', 'Account is temporarily blocked.');
      } else if (isset($_SESSION['error_count'][$username]) && $_SESSION['error_count'][$username] > 2) {
        $this->account_login_model->block($username);
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_user', '3 consecutive failed login attempts. Account Blocked.');
      } else {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_user', 'Invalid Username/Password');
      }
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

**Model**

```
<?php
class account_login_model extends CI_Model
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
  }

  public function login($username, $password)
  {
    $condition_array = array(
      'acc_username' => $username,
      'acc_password' => $password
    );
    $rs = $this->db->get_where('accounts', $condition_array);

    return $rs->row_array() ?: false;
   
  }

  public function isBlocked($username)
  {
    $condition_array = array(
      'acc_username' => $username,
      'acc_isBlocked' => 1
    );
    $rs = $this->db->get_where('accounts', $condition_array);
    $row_count = count($condition_array);

    if ($row_count > 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return FALSE;
    }
  }

  public function block($username)
  {
    $this->load->library('email');

    $email = $this->account_lookup($username, 'acc_email');

    $this->email->from('<email>', 'Yahoo.com');
    $this->email->to($email);
    $this->email->subject('Account Blocked');

    $message = $this->load->view('account_blocked', null, TRUE);

    $this->email->message($message);
    $this->email->send();

    $this->db->where('acc_username', $username);
    return $this->db->update('accounts', array('acc_isBlocked' => 1));
  }

  public function account_lookup($username, $return)
  {
    $rs = $this->db->get_where('account', array('acc_username' => $username));
    $row = $rs->row();
    return $row->$return;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please do not post your real email address in your question.

Comment: try `if ($isBlocked !== false)`

Comment: In `isBlocked()` on this line: `$row_count = count($condition_array);` Why are you counting `$condition_array`  ? As per your condition this will always return `false`

Comment: @mPareek - I think you mean that it will always return `true`? The condition array contains 2 items so `$row_count` will definitely be `> 0`.

Comment: @Ashok I tried, doesn't work. Thank you

Comment: @Ronald Balza Please do not post your real email address in your question.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson my bad! Yes, it will return `true`

Comment: @KUMAR got you. Thanks!

Comment: @RonaldBalza have you checked my comment above and the condition?

Comment: @mPareek yes I did. so I made ($isBlocked !== TRUE) it somehow worked and I got another error which is now the SMTP. thanks.